# How to prove the union of a convergent sequence and its limit is a closed set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in a metric space $M$ which converges to $x$. Prove that $\{x_n|n \in N\}\cup\{x\}$ is a closed subset of N.

I've tried the direct way or the contradiction way but worked out neither of them. I feel that the proof by contradiction is a good candidate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's prove it's even compact, hence closed.

Let $\{G_k: k \in K\}$ be an open cover of your set. Then $x \in G_k$ for some $k \in K$. Since $G_k$ is open, there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that the ball $B_M(x, \epsilon) \subseteq G_k$. This is good news: because $x_n \to x$, there is $n_0 \geq 1$ such that $d(x_n, x) < \epsilon$ if $n \geq n_0$ and thus $x_n \in G_k$ if $n \geq n_0$. Now, choose indices $k_1, \dots, k_{n_0-1}$ such that $x_i \in G_{k_i}$ for $i=1, \dots, n_0-1$. Then

$$\{G_k, G_{k_1}, \dots, G_{k_{n_0}-1}\}$$

is a finite subcover, proving that your set is compact. $\quad \square$